# Can you set a field to not_analyzed in an auto created index in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, terraform, chalice

As part of our AWS infrastructure, I am using an Elasticsearch (7.4) index. We use Terraform to create the domain in AWS Elasticsearch but we don't create the index explicitly. Instead when the first document is posted, the index is auto-created. This worked well, but now I have been given the requirement to have a non analyzed field (user id).

Is there a way to make a field `not_analyzed` when putting the first document?

If there is **not**, what are my options to set the field to `not_analyzed`? Should I do some sort of init/bootstrapping? Maybe there is a way to do it from Terraform. The application is build using Chalice and runs in Lambda. Not sure how to do initialization in Lambda in that case. Ideally I would fire this call a single time:

```
PUT /my_index
{
    "mappings" : {
          "properties" : {
              "user_id" : {
                  "type" : "string",
                  "index" : "not_analyzed" 
              }
          }
    }

}
```

When restarting the application, this call would be send again but I guess it's immutable (PUT).

Comment: there is no longer a string type in ES 7.x. Instead, for non-analyzed fields, you'd use keyword. What is creating the mapping for you?

Comment: It would be the default mapping I guess, when you auto create an index by posting the first document.

Comment: If you're using v7.x, it isn't the default mapping, as that isn't a supported type anymore. Perhaps you're still in 5.x? Regardless, check out "dynamic templates" which give you control over how the dynamic mapping maps new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be an overkill but I would consider using [index template feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/index-templates.html)

This may look like

```
PUT _index_template/template_1
{
  "index_patterns": [
    "my_template*"
  ],
  "template": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "user_id" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "priority": 1
}
```

It can be terraformed using dedicated [provider](https://github.com/phillbaker/terraform-provider-elasticsearch) - it also integrates directly with AWS Elasticsearch using IAM keys.

Then first document created in that way will also build an index using given template (of course if name will match the pattern)

Comment: Excellent suggestion, which I just tried. Unfortunately the feature was added in 7.8 which AWS does not support yet (eu-west-1). I will check the old way to do the same thing.

Comment: @reikje Templates are in ES since long time, AFAIR they are there since 2.X versions at least. They simply renamed it from `template` to `index_template` that's why you cannot find it in documentation. See here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/indices-templates.html for version 7.4 docs

Comment: I got it working on the old syntax thanks. It was a great suggestion thanks. I didnt use the TF provider since it was for 0.13 and we are still on 0.12. I simply created another Lambda that can be run manually after terraform deploy. Not super automated but good enough :)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but for your problem I would suggest a solution outside Elasticsearch:

- Provision a second Lambda function in Terraform that will be permitted to run PUT operations against Elasticsearch, and has a sole purpose of creating your index.
- In Terraform, invoke this lambda function once the domain is created

In other words, perform the bootstrapping mentioned in your question, but move it to a separate lambda function instead of it being mixed into your application lambda.

Comment: I see but I can probably just find a way to do a HTTP PUT request from Terraform after the setup has completed. One way to do this, would be to use the `local-exec` provisioner.